# How different is the Japanese PS3 version of Shadows of the Damned?

Tags: ps3, shadows-of-the-damned

I am considering buying *Shadows of the Damned* for the PlayStation 3, but I am not sure which localized version is the best: Japanese, American, or European.

I was disappointed when I bought the PS3 Japanese version of *No More Heroes* (developed by the same studio, Grasshopper Manufacture) because the blood and gory boss executions were replaced by softer content: I wanted the original B-movie style content.

Is *Shadows of the Damned* censored the same way in Japan?

Comment: Hi wil, welcome to Gaming! I removed your unrelated question: consider asking a second question about whether the Japanese version of the game contains English translations.

Comment: I would wonder why you'd want the Japanese version in the first place. I think a game starring a Mexican protagonist would sound better in English than in Japanese. But that's just me. Also, since the European/US version retail for much less than the JP version (which came out later), why even take the risk if you're so worried the game might be censored.

Comment: If you live in Japan or a country near Japan, it's probably cheaper/easier to buy the Japanese version.

Comment: @JohnoBoy as suggested Joe Wreschnig it would be cheaper and quicker for me to get the japanese version, but I don't mind waiting/paying for a "better" version. Then about your comment : would not a game starring a Mexican protagonist sound better in spanish :-D Also sometimes the japanese version of a game is uncensored while the export version is cut, that's why I' m asking for this particular game.

Comment: OK, I see your points :)
I'm playing the game myself right now and the English dub is top-notch, plus you can get it for really cheap off UK sites like Zavvi.com 
Unless you wan't the Japanese dub or the Japanese bonuses, I'd recommend playing it safe and just getting the UK version which isn't censored as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The japanese version does not seem censored (blood is depicted on enemy destruction, etc.). Also, there is an option to select japanese or english dialogue. Finally all the menus are translated in english (depending on console settings, I guess).
Therefore, I declare that the japanese version is suitable for international usage, and not different from the other localized versions.

Comment: Update: actually, there seems to be a few censored scenes, such as described in this discussion:  http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/952594-shadows-of-the-damned/62920622 and http://www.gaijingamers.com/showthread.php?t=5568